# How to design chat talking layout has leftside and rightside when use Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Firebase realtime databse to complete chat app.

I want to design when the name is `Tom`, the textView will show on right side side, others will show on left side.

Here's my layout: two textView design for left and right:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/ic_send"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textLeft"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="It's left >" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textRight"//It's for Tom
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="It's right >"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my chat activity class:

```
    public class Chat_Room extends AppCompatActivity {

        private Button button2;
        private TextView textLeft,textRight;
        private EditText editText2;

        private String room_name, user_name;
        private String myName;

        private DatabaseReference root;
        private DatabaseReference rootName;
        private String temp_key;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.chat_room);

            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            textLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textLeft);
            textRight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textRight);
            editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

            user_name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("user_name").toString();
            room_name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("room_name").toString();

            setTitle("Room name:" + room_name);

            root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);//

            Log.d("Name is : ",rootName+"");

//send text msg
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    temp_key = root.push().getKey();
                    root.updateChildren(map);

                    DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
                    Map<String, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
                    map2.put("name", user_name);
                    map2.put("msg", editText2.getText().toString());

                    message_root.updateChildren(map2);
                }
            });

            root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    myName= dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.d("Name is : ",myName);

                        append_Right_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    //append_right_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
                }


                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

        }

        private String chat_msg, chat_user_name;


        private void append_Right_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

            chat_msg=(String) ((DataSnapshot)(i.next())).getValue();
            chat_user_name=(String) ((DataSnapshot)(i.next())).getValue();

            textRight.append(chat_user_name+":"+chat_msg+" \n");

    //        textLeft.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

        }
    }
```

Here's my Database Structure:

[image]

I try to use this code on onCreatView:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (myName.equals("Tom")) {
                    textRight.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {

                }

            }
        }).start();
```

But it's not working. :(

Can anyone can give some suggestions or a sample? Thanks in advance.

Edit- It shows like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gaszh.png)

Comment: In your sample code, you only have two `TextView` so your chat will only contain 2 message. Is it intentional?

Comment: i had override onChildAdded , it will add dynamicly , just like the photo that i have update.

Comment: Can you try to *sensor out* the profanity? Doesn't really look that good. With that said, I think it would be better that you just dynamically add `TextView`s to ListView of some sort. It'll be easier. Check out the [Firebase Codelab - Friendly Chat](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0) and simply modify the alignment settings when the sender/user is the one you need.

Comment: a little hard to follow , i still take a look , thanks for your sample